# Installing IDJC in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I upgraded Ubuntu Studio (Desktop) to 20.04 LTS and want to install [IDJC](http://idjc.sourceforge.net/).

From what I am seeing on launchpad.net it is supposed to be in the repo but I am unable to install it.  Anyone know of what I need to do?

Console output when trying to install based on IDJC's website instructions:

```
sudo apt install idjc Reading package lists... 
Done Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... 
Done Package idjc is not available, but is referred to by another package. 
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source 
E: Package 'idjc' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Console output when trying to install based on IDJC's website instructions:

[code]
sudo apt install idjc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package idjc is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'idjc' has no installation candidate
[/code]

Answer (score 0):

The [IDJC pages at Sourceforge.net](http://idjc.sourceforge.net/install_build.html) also explain what you experienced happens when they don't have a package ready, and explains how you can resolve dependencies and install from source.

They say to run this command to resolve the dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libc6-dev libglib2.0-dev libjack-dev jackd libvorbis-dev libsamplerate0-dev libsndfile1-dev python-gtk2-dev libmpg123-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libtwolame-dev libmp3lame-dev libflac-dev python-mutagen libspeex-dev
```

then offer the steps required to build from source, after you Click the relevant link for downloading *libshout-idjc* from that web page (currently https://sourceforge.net/projects/libshoutidjc.idjc.p/files/libshout-idjc-2.4.2.tar.gz/download/ to get version **2.4.2**), then in a console type the following.

```
cd Downloads  
tar xzvf libshout-idjc-[version].tar.gz  
cd libshout-idjc-[version]/  
./configure CFLAGS="-O2" --prefix=/usr  
make  
sudo make install  
sudo ldconfig
```

Navigate to http://sourceforge.net/projects/idjc/ and hit the big green **Download** button. Wait for the download to finish. Make a note of the version number, then complete the install with

```
cd Downloads  
tar xzvf idjc-[version].tar.gz  
cd idjc-[version]/  
./configure CFLAGS="-O2" --prefix=/usr  
make  
sudo make install
```